# 301 Redirect in .htaccess removing extension but keeping URL parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, parameters

I want to do a 301 redirect on links with parameters, I need to keep the parameter in the URL but remove the .php file extension.
I need something to redirect from : `/checkout.php?sku=2FA-DEF` to `/checkout?sku=2FA-DEF`.
I have different values for the 'sku' parameter, but it only contains letters, numbers, and hyphens.

Firstly, I tried something like this :

```
RedirectPermanent   /checkout.php?sku=2FA-DEF   /checkout?sku=2FA-DEF 
RedirectPermanent   /checkout.php?sku=G-DEF-1   /checkout?sku=G-DEF-1
```

But I think RedirectPermanent can't work with URL parameters ? So I tried a lot of things with RewriteCond and RewriteRule, but I don't know anything about regex, redirection, etc.. so unfortunately I can't make it work...

Some help would be very appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: mod_rewrite with [QSA](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/RewriteFlags+QSA) would be more flexible.

Comment: @CD001 yes I think too, but I can't make it work with this..

Comment: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=75d47d44-9594-5cd7-a212-efdb2f0a8c78 <- something like that?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need, but when I put it in my .htaccess, it doesn't work.. I got a 404 when I go on https://mywebsite.com/checkout.php?sku=2FA-DEF ...

Comment: I've a *sneaky* suspicion that you want to actually do the opposite of what you asked. You want to display `mywebsite.com/checkout?sku=2FA-DEF` in the address bar while **really** calling checkout.php (behind the scenes)? In which case it would be something more like: https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=e87ef4eb-56d0-56e0-b669-c7bbef554026

Comment: Mhmm.. no, i don't think so (maybe I'm wrong) but I just want that when I type `mywebsite.com/checkout.php?sku=2FA-DEF` in my address bar, It redirect me to `mywebsite.com/checkout?sku=2FA-DEF`

Comment: So you actually have a file called `checkout` ?